# How can use Alias filed in FastReport.net

Tags: fastreport

i need to pass custom query to FastRepoert.net and this query is used alias field but i can't use this filed in fastreport.net
for example in this code how can use total field in my report ?

```
select sum(price) as total from account
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when creating new data source in report design in the tables choose page click "add sql query ..." and enter your query after this the new table with alias field is created and can be used